# Group XDocument.Descandants

Tags: xml, linq, grouping

How to group xml element values

```
XDocument.Descandants("Customer").GroupBy(c=>c.Element("ServiceId"));
```

This is not working.

Is there any way to group this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ServiceId is a child element of Customer at your Xml, you can group your customers by ServiceId's value by :

```
XDocument.Descandants("Customer")
     .GroupBy(c=>c.Element("ServiceId").Value);
```

If ServiceId is an attribute of Customer element, try this :

```
XDocument.Descandants("Customer")
     .GroupBy(c=>c.Attribute("ServiceId").Value);
```